# What mathematical models can analyze and optimize systems based on gossip?

Tags: graph-theory, game-theory, mathematical-modeling

I look for a mathematical model that can accommodate, analyze and suggest optimizations for a system that can be humanly described as people gossiping about stuff.

### System description:

We have a graph. Its nodes can appear and disappear in time (we know only if node is alive at a discreet moment of time). Each node has a set $M $ of parameters describing their state. We do not know lows of how parameters change, but we know that they change as time goes on and new messages arrive so we can try to approximate them for each node. We can assume that all nodes can be connected one to another. Nodes send different messages to one to another, messages are different, we know some hash function-based signature for each message and its size. We have $f(size, t, c) $ that describes how fast a message can be passed from one node to another, it uses message size, current time, and $c $ for size of all other messages being sent to this node concurrently.

### Task at hand

A node can be called "happy" if it receives and sends as much messages as possible, while its values of set $M $ are as low as possible, or if it sends and receives none messages and values of set $M $ are as low as possible.

We cannot control when a node sends a new message we can only tell to the node having $t $ message hash and size where to send it to. Our task is to make as much nodes happy as possible.

What game or any other mathematical modes can help us to suggest whom to tall the new gossip?

Comment: You might google "message-passing algorithm".

Comment: Rather than ask "what kind of mathematical model can help", can't you be more specific about what you are doing and where you are stuck? In its current form the question looks too open-ended

Comment: I seek for a theoretical studies that encountered/solved such or similar problem. At least mathematical models which allows such problem to be solved in your opinion. So a name of the theory + reference to a paper with a model would be the answer

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind for me is a note about a secondary school lesson plan; on the off chance that it is of any use, [**here**](http://www.iitgn.ac.in/mcm/cd/Mathematical%20Modelling%20Handbook/pdf/19_ViralMarketing.pdf#8) is a link to the page 8 excerpt from this lesson in COMAP's *Mathematical Modeling Handbook*.